Entity Framework C# join with one column only from second table
I have a join in Entity Framework connecting the Order and the OrderItem tables. All orders will have multiple order items. I'm trying to return all the orders, but only the orderItemStatus column from the OrderItem list.
In my Order model class, I have this property:
public List<int>? orderItemStatus { get; set; }

I'm joining the 2 tables ok, but it's returning all columns from the OrderItem.
orderList = await _context.Order
                          .Include(orderItem => orderItem)
                          .ToListAsync();

How do I get a list of the orders with just the OrderItem.orderItemStatus values?
Order Table

OrderItem Table

Required Results - the OrderItemStatus column can be a List<> or comma delimited


Did you try anything? If we see your efforts, including the class definitions. and where you're stuck we also understand the question.

Yes, as per answer to Mark below. I still can't get the join working on a single column

Managed to get it working with GroupJoin
 result = await _context.Order
        .GroupJoin(_context.OrderItem,
        order => order.OrderID,
        orderItem => orderItem.OrderID,
        (Order, OrderItemStatus) => new OrderIndex
        {
            OrderID = Order.OrderID,
            //other Order properties here
            OrderItemStatus = OrderItemStatus.Select(x => x.OrderItemStatus).ToList(),
        }).ToListAsync();


Have you tried something like this:
   orderList = await  _context.Order
            .Join(_context.OrderItem,
                o => o.OrderId,
                oi => oi.OrderId,
                (o,oi) => new { o,io })
            .Select(ol => new
            {
                OrderId = o.Order.OrderId,
                /* Order columns  here */
                OrderItemStatus = oi.OrderItem.orderItemStatus
            })
            .ToListAsync();

This selects into an anonymous class but you could define a class and select into it

Tried that thanks. I can't assign the List of oi.OrderItem.orderItemStatus values to the OrderItemStatus - can't convert int to List<>.

Can you add the schema you’re working with in order to visualize this?

Edited with data examples


How do I get a list of the orders with just the
OrderItem.orderItemStatus values?  I can't assign the List of oi.OrderItem.orderItemStatus values to the OrderItemStatus - can't convert int to List<>

Based on your secenario and description along with the shared code snippet, you could use a projection with LINQ to select the desired columns.
In order to implement that, you would need to define a view model to hold the result set. Then use a LINQ query with Select to project the result into your view model.
Let's have a look in practice, how we could implement that:
Let's say you have model like below:
Domain Model:
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public int OrderItemStatus { get; set; }
}

View Model for projection:
public class OrderWithStatusViewModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<int> OrderItemStatus { get; set; }
}

Demo Controller:
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OrdersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("GetSampleOrdersWithStatus")]
    public ActionResult<List<OrderWithStatusViewModel>> GetSampleOrdersWithStatus()
    {
        var sampleOrders = new List<Order>
        {
            new Order
            {
                OrderId = 1,
                OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>
                {
                    new OrderItem { OrderItemId = 1, OrderItemStatus = 1 },
                    new OrderItem { OrderItemId = 2, OrderItemStatus = 2 }
                }
            },
            new Order
            {
                OrderId = 2,
                OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>
                {
                    new OrderItem { OrderItemId = 3, OrderItemStatus = 3 },
                    new OrderItem { OrderItemId = 4, OrderItemStatus = 4 }
                }
            }
        };

        var result = sampleOrders.Select(order => new OrderWithStatusViewModel
        {
            OrderId = order.OrderId,
            OrderItemStatus = order.OrderItems.Select(item => item.OrderItemStatus).ToList()
        }).ToList();

        return Ok(result);
  
    
    }
}

Note:


Note: In order to simulate your scenario, I have used demo sample data within calling the DbContext, You could pull the data directly from your DbContext. If you would like to know more about Linq Project sample and implementation, please refer to this official document.
